# How to routing our asp.net url?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net, visual-studio

My url is 
**PrintProductInvoice.aspx?id=39&n=I** and i want to route our url like PrintProduct/abc. Id get by data base.

How to change our url.

Comment: It's unclear what your question is. Could you elaborate?

Comment: It seems, You want to customize the URL with help of ASP.Net Routing concept. If yes, Then refer this https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/77199/URL-Routing-with-ASP-NET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question, I think you want to be able to generate URL's patterns that are not dependent on physical file names.

This can be achieved by making use of the ASP.NET Routing.

This is what your route configuration will look like more or less:

```
void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
     routes.MapPageRoute("PrintRoute",
        "PrintProduct/{product}",
        "~/PrintProductInvoice.aspx");
}
```

Which you will be able to call as: 'http://youraddress.com/PrintProduct/abc'

IN order to configure your routes, you will need to do some minimal setup work in your project, as outlined in the article [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd329551.aspx)